# How do I center tabs in a vertical navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, navbar

So I have a vertical navbar, and I haven't been able to center the tabs. The text is too far off to the right, and when I hover over it, the highlighted box doesn't extend to the margins. My code is below:

HTML:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
       <head>
         <title>Matthew H. Goodman</title>
         <link href="style2home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
       </head>
       <body>
         <ul id="nav">
           <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">RESEARCH</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
         </ul>
       </body>
     </html>
```

CSS:

```
     #nav {
       margin-top: 200px;
       left: 0;
       width: auto;
       height: auto;
       border-radius: 10px;
       position: absolute;
       background-image: url("http://www.diiiz.com/variant/Argent%C3%A9.jpg"); 
     }

     #nav li {
       position: relative;
       list-style: none;
       padding: 15px;
       width: auto;
     }

     #nav li a {
       position: relative;
       display: block;
       text-decoration: none;
       font-size: 15px;
       font-weight: bold;
       color: white;
       text-align: center;
     }

     #nav li a:hover {
       color: #778899;
       background-color: black;

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers, and some CSS resets add default rules to elements like UL/OL to keep style-less html elements looking consistent.

```
ul#nav { padding-left: 0; }
```

I would recommend using a CSS reset (normalize, eric meyer's reset, etc) to allow you to start from scratch. 
Use chrome/firefox/ie11 dev tools (F12, or right click and inspect element), go to the element in the window and hover over it to see the margin/padding rules. Scroll down the CSS rules on the right side to find where they are being applied Or click on 'computed styles' to see all the rules.

For the hover states,
you need to apply your hover to the li and handle the color separately

```
#nav li:hover { background-color: black; }
#nav li:hover a  { color: #778899; }
```

You also need to add

```
#nav { overflow: hidden; }
```

to maintain your border-radius

Comment: Also, this will make the links not quite as 'clickable',
move your li padding to the a tag, and display block 100% 100%

`#nav li a { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 15px; }`

Comment: Sure thing!
If everything works well, please `accept` my answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have some padding being applied to your `#nav` element you can fix it by adding:

```
 #nav {padding:0px;}
```

To make the background cover the entire line add more padding to `a` and remove padding from the `li` with the current markup that will do the trick.

```
li {padding:0px;}
a {padding:15px;}
```

you can insted add a `hover` state to the li element but that but that will cause some problems with being able to click the a element correctly.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the centering problem, but how would I get the black highlight to fill the width of the div?

Comment: You have padding added to the `li` element and a hover state on the anchor link so it wont fill the li element just the a. Remove the padding from the `li` and add more padding to `a`.